# Attribute Error: 'float' object has no attribute

Tags: python, user-interface, attributeerror

I'm still new to python and I'm trying to create a GUI to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit. I'm doing some practice problems from my textbook and I think I almost have it but this last little bit has me stuck! I keep getting `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'set'`. Here is the portion of code in question

UPDATE: I'm adding the full program as a commenter suggested it would be more helpful to see.

```
 #This program uses a GUI to get the Celsius temperature and convert it to Fahrenheit
import tkinter

class Converter:
    def __init__(self):
        #create the main window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        #create the three frames
        self.cel_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.fah_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        #create and pack the widgets for cel
        self.cel_label = tkinter.Label(self.cel_frame, \
                                       text='Enter the Celsius temperature: ')
        self.cel_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.cel_frame,\
                                       width=10)
        self.cel_label.pack(side='left')
        self.cel_entry.pack(side='left')

        #create and pack the widgets for fah
        self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.fah_frame, \
                                          text='Fahrenheit temperature: ')
        self.fah = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.fah_label = tkinter.Label(self.fah_frame, \
                                       textvariable=self.fah)
        self.result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.fah_label.pack(side='left')

        #create and pack the button widgets
        self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, \
                                          text='Convert to Fahrenheit', \
                                          command=self.calc_fah)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, \
                                          text='Quit', \
                                          command=self.main_window.destroy)
        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        #Pack the frames
        self.cel_frame.pack()
        self.fah_frame.pack()
        self.button_frame.pack()

        #start the main loop
        tkinter.mainloop()

    #callback
    def calc_fah(self):
        #Get Celsius temperature and store in variables
        self.cel = float(self.cel_entry.get())

        #Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit
        self.fah = ((9/5) * self.cel + 32)

        #update the fah_label widget 
        self.fah.set(fahrenheit)
        
#create an instance of Converter class
test_converter = Converter()
```

Comment: Well you just set your `self.fah` to `float object` (`self.fah = ((9/5) * self.cel + 32)`), so it throws `AttributeError` because of `self.fah.set` You mean `fahrenheit = ((9/5) * self.cel + 32)`?

Comment: @cylee I think I'm realizing I'm more confused/messed up then when I posted this- I was so confident...haha!

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the `tkinter.StringVar` reference. @cylee is right, you should change the line above that to `fahrenheit = (9/5) * self.cel + 32`.

Comment: @Selcuk thank you both so much!!!!! I've been trying to figure this out almost all day!!! such a silly and simple fix I missed- Thank you so much for helping out this newbie!!

Comment: @cylee thank you both so much!!!!! I've been trying to figure this out almost all day!!! such a silly and simple fix I missed- Thank you so much for helping out this newbie!!